# Couldn't revert my edit, people just don't approve it. What else can I do?

Tags: support

This is the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/449000/revisions).

I even explicitly tell them this is a rollback, but the people who reviewed it just keep rejecting, saying "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post." It obviously doesn't. They just don't even bother to look at the comment I left.

What else could I do to rollback the edit I made?

Comment: do you have a link to the revision that's being rejected? we can't see what your trying to roll back too

Comment: @Memor-X - OP edited an answer, not the question they linked to: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/449000/revisions

Comment: Generally, you don't want to attempt rollbacks when you're under 2K rep.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Edit reviewers make mistakes.  Many don't take the time to understand the edit and why it was made.  Many will automatically reject edits to code in answers and only a precisely clear edit summary will catch their attention.  Your original (wrong) edit was actually an anomaly in that it got approved.

But your original (wrong) edit is an excellent reason why we don't want reviewers just approving edits to code in answers. They aren't subject matter experts. Normally you should not try to fix answers with significant edits to code to change an answer. If you think something is wrong, leave a comment, and/or downvote, and/or leave your own answer. Had you done that, you wouldn't need to fix anything except deleted your wrong answer.

---

But you made 2 big mistakes in trying to fix the problem.

First, your edit summaries did not clearly explain that **your** previous edit was wrongly approved and you were trying to fix it.  You hinted at it and danced around it, but none of those edit summaries completely summarized the problem and explained exactly why you needed to revert the edit.  The 3rd one comes closest, but even it is lacking a very key details - you are trying to fix a wrong approved edit that you made yourself.

Second, once you sort of expanded your summary and tried to explain it was a rollback, you started getting a little frustrated and it showed in your edit description (you don't need to start yelling at reviewers in the edit summary - it is a sure fire sign that someone has been rejected multiple times and keeps trying to propose the same edit).

Here's a summary of each of them:

> 1. fixing my own mistakes: the name must be at least 2 characters long only if the first char is -
> 2. See the "There is a catch" part: (only) if the first character is a hyphen, … the name must be at least 2 characters long
> 3. : !!!ROLLBACK please!!! The author (ME) of the latest edit (the regexp) to this answer misread the "There is a catch" part, which is actually: (only) if the first character is a hyphen… the name must be at least 2 characters long
> 4. !!!Please note that this is a rollback!!! Don't give me that "edit deviates from the original intent of the post" bullshit
> 5. !!!Please note that this is a rollback!!! Don't give me that "edit deviates from the original intent of the post" bullshit.

My suggestion is to be more precise in the edit summary and with less fluff:

> ***My previous suggested edit to this answer was wrongly approved and I am trying to revert my incorrect changes to restore the post to the previous state.***

Had you done that, you most likely wouldn't have needed 5 attempts to fix your original mistake.

But in the future, if you ever see a post that clearly needs fixed for some reason and you do not have fully edit privileges and your suggested edit was rejected, just drop into a chat room and explain the situation.  A user with edit privileges will usually be more than happy to help you edit. Don't just keep proposing the same edit over and over again.

Comment: I'll keep your words in mind. Really appreciate your kind advice.

Comment: "only a precisely clear edit summary will catch their attention" hahahahahahahhahahaha, no.

Comment: @Braiam: Well, let's put it this way: if it's anything other than a ridiculously boring, obviously-good edit, only the best of edit summaries will have the slightest chance of salvaging it from the horde of vicious edit rejecters. :P